# Azure az login after successful login not to display details

Tags: azure, shell, azure-cli2

Are there any option in azure cli not to display the JSON formatted output with tenantid, subscription details after successfully authenticated using `az login` command.

I am building a shell script, where i first use `az login` then fetch secret info from keyvault using below command

```
az keyvault secret show --vault-name "name-of-keyvault" --name "secret-key-name" --query "value" --output tsv
```

and doing my requirement.

if there are option/switch like -q or --quite, not to print the output it would not clutter the output.

Being Linux i can redirect this output to stdout, but if already there is another option within the cli it will be good to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding **--help** would have shown you that you can suppress the output:

```
--output -o : Output format.  Allowed values: json, jsonc, none, table, tsv, yaml, yamlc.  Default: json.
```

Comment: great i see it in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login).. my bad using dark theme i missed the Global Parameter link toggle.